How to optimize assembly emit for LLVM?
Hi here is the code that emit riscv assembly:
  // create machine
  module.setTargetTriple(triple);
  std::string error;
  auto target =
      llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(module.getTargetTriple(), error);
  llvm::TargetOptions opt;
  if (enable_fp_fusion)
    opt.AllowFPOpFusion = llvm::FPOpFusion::Fast;
  opt.UnsafeFPMath = false;
  opt.NoInfsFPMath = false;
  opt.NoNaNsFPMath = true;
  opt.TrapUnreachable = true;
  std::unique_ptr<llvm::TargetMachine> machine{target->createTargetMachine(
      module.getTargetTriple(), proc, features, opt, llvm::Reloc::PIC_,
      std::nullopt, llvm::CodeGenOptLevel::Aggressive)};
  // set data layout
  module.setDataLayout(machine->createDataLayout());
  // emit machine code
  std::string result;
  {
    llvm::raw_string_ostream stream(result);
    llvm::buffer_ostream pstream(stream);
    for (llvm::Function &f : module.functions())
      f.addFnAttr(llvm::Attribute::AlwaysInline);
    llvm::legacy::PassManager pass;
    // emit
    auto fileType = isObject ? llvm::CodeGenFileType::ObjectFile
                             : llvm::CodeGenFileType::AssemblyFile;
    machine->addPassesToEmitFile(pass, pstream, nullptr, fileType);
    pass.run(module);
  }

I found that the result assembly contains:
    slli    a3, a3, 32
    srli    a3, a3, 30

How can I apply optimization on produced riscv assembly??
Thanks
